# NuxtJS build takes up all resources

Tags: ubuntu, nuxt.js, digital-ocean, vps, nuxtjs

I am deploying my NuxtJS app using a deployment script, which I added below. I use some of the instructions from this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-deployment-using-circleci-and-github-on-ubuntu-18-04

If I access my droplet using SSH and run the `deploy.sh` script manually, it seems to work fine. But as soon as CircleCI starts a docker instance (see config.yml below), it needs at least 5 minutes to run the script, if I am lucky. And while doing that, the CPU of my droplet spikes, and it takes a lot of patience trying to reconnect with my droplet using SSH from my local machine.

Quite odd this only seem to happen when running the script through CircleCI. Just in case, I tried to spin up a medium docker instance, instead of a small, but without luck. Most of the time, the deployment is killed after 10 minutes, so I end up with a failed deployment most of the time.

If CircleCI fails, my droplet’s CPU stays over 100% and `node_modules/.bin/nuxt build` keeps running. Rebooting the droplet is the easiest solution (sometimes necessary, if reconnecting using SSH just isn’t possible or the terminal which is already connected, isn’t responding anymore). After reboot, the first CircleCi deployment succeeds and the rest fail again.

I looked at htop, and it seems that `kswapd0` takes over 40% CPU, `snapd` over 30 and the rest are for node, etc.

deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#move to project folder
cd /var/www/mywebsite.nl

#pull from the branch
git pull origin main

# build nuxt project and run pm2
npm install
npm run build

pm2 start
```

circleci config.yml

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:trusty
    resource_class: small   # we use a small docker instance to use as little credits as possible
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
      - run:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: |
              ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -v $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "./deploy.sh"
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - main # only deploy on the main branch
```

nuxt.config.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack'


export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'server',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'myapp',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/sass/main'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [{
    src: '~plugins/vue-scrollmagic.js',
    ssr: false
  }],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [

  ['nuxt-fontawesome', {
    component: 'fa', //customize component name
    imports: [{
        set: '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        icons: ['fab']
        },
      ]
    }]
  ],

  build: {
    loaders:  {
      vue: {
         prettify: false
      }
    }
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
  ],

  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://mydomain.nl'
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

My droplet: 1 GB Memory / 25 GB Disk / AMS3 - Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64

Answer (score 0):

Saving some memory for other processes, by setting the `--max-old-space-size` parameter on the build process in `package.json` seems to solve this. My app was deployed in under a minute.

```
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=600 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build"
```

Sometimes this isn't enough when my machine is actually using more memory at some point, so I guess the safest option is to use 2GB.

On the other hand this only happens during the build of the app, so I guess I might report an issue on GitHub just in case.

Comment: HI, i have same problem, is this proper solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862314/nuxt-js-program-in-uses-all-resources